# List Sorting (ascending and descending order)

Tags: python, list

Question: Get input from user in the form of list and arrange the elements of the list according to the ascending and descending order.

```
   list = eval(input("Enter the elements of the list")) 
   a = list.sort() 
   print("Sorted in ascending order: ", a) 
   d = list.sort(reverse = True) 
   print("Sorted in descending order: ", d)
```

This is the code I tried, but it shows error. Can you please help me?

Comment: can you also share the error which you get ?

Comment: Please show some input.

Comment: `list.sort` sorts in place and returns `None`. Don't assign the result. Just output `list` (which you should rename).

Comment: OR use `a = sorted(my_list) ` instead to get new list

Comment: None of the offered answers good enough to accept?

Answer (score 0):

list.sort() return Nome, so the variable a is reciving a none value i fixed like this :

```
list = input("Enter the elements of the list, comma separate : ").split(',')
list.sort()
a = list
print("Sorted in ascending order: ", a) 
list.sort(reverse = True) 
b = list
print("Sorted in descending order: ", b)
```

and this was the result with int

```
Enter the elements of the list, comma separate : 1,7,8,9,7,5,4,6
Sorted in ascending order:  ['1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7', '8', '9']
Sorted in descending order:  ['9', '8', '7', '7', '6', '5', '4', '1']
```

and with strings

```
Enter the elements of the list, comma separate : a,b,r,e,ra
Sorted in ascending order:  ['a', 'b', 'e', 'r', 'ra']
Sorted in descending order:  ['ra', 'r', 'e', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @John's answer, you should rename `list` to something else, since `list` is already in use by python as a type. Here's an example:

```
user_input = input("Enter the elements of the list, comma separated: ").split(',')
user_input.sort()
print("Sorted in ascending order: ", user_input) 
user_input.sort(reverse = True) 
print("Sorted in descending order: ", user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort` does not return the sorted list; rather, it sorts the list in place. The below code works fine

```
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : ")) 
a = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:n] 
b=sorted(a)
print("Sorted in ascending order: ", b) 
c = sorted(a,reverse = True) 
print("Sorted in descending order: ", c)
```